# Any exemption on the grounds of age for obtaining British Nationality?

Tags: citizenship, uk-citizenship

I have been living in the UK for the past 25 years on an ILR.   I am over 80 years of age and would now like to acquire British nationality  but no longer have the mental retention  to complete the comprehensive test.  Are there any exemptions made for those of senior age? I am also no longer able to travel long distances.

Answer (score 7):

I am not a lawyer, but apparently if you are over 65 you do not have to pass the language test and the Life in the UK test, see the links below:

https://www.gov.uk/english-language

https://www.gov.uk/life-in-the-uk-test

and also

https://www.gov.uk/browse/citizenship/citizenship